# Switch sample rates in PulseAudio automatically, based on currently selected input device?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a Logitech C310 USB webcam with a mic that records in mono @16000Hz. My computer's built-in soundcard / line in input records @44100Hz. `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` uses the `default-sample-rate` of 44100.

I don't currently use the built-in soundcard for anything, and rely on the webcam mic for voice chats. At the current default sample rate, everything comes in sped up and high-pitched, like Alvin and the Chipmunks. Changing the pulse config file to use a sample rate of 16000 fixes it, which is great, but I'd rather not have to remember that I manually changed a config file somewhere if/when I want to use the built-in soundcard for recording in the future.

Is there any way to configure PulseAudio to switch sample rates automatically based on the currently selected input device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in pulseaudio. Could you create a bug report? You could try different resample methods and/or setting "avoid-resampling = yes" in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf for pulseaudio 11.0 or higher (see [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/11.0/)).

Comment: My issue is more that I'm not entirely sure how pulseaudio is supposed to work, and whether what I am asking for is supported or even the correct approach. Perhaps it's a bug, but perhaps there simply needs to be more layperson-level documentation on how to configure and use pulseaudio?

Comment: I think the output sound should be normal even if have default sample rate 44100Hz (and 48000Hz as alternative sample rate). Then pulseaudio should resample the 16000Hz sample rate input to given sample rate using given resample method.  You can see available resample methods by running `pulseaudio --dump-resample-methods` in terminal. You can give resample method as an option for pulseaudio when you (re)start it. Do you mean your recordings are sped up? What software do you use for recording?